# Convert datetime json string to date

Tags: php, laravel-4

I got JSON object with date property like this

```
"date": 1402680443
```

How can I convert it with PHP to show just the date in Jan 00 0000 format ?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Are you creating the JSON and trying to format it correctly? Or are you receiving this JSON and trying to convert the number to text?

Comment: no, not duplicate not helps... I need to parse it in PHP

Comment: I'm not creating, I get the JSON from Stripe API to my Laravel app and I need to output only the date in a normal format on my blade template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use function date(); 
`date("Y-m-d H:i:s", 1402680443);`

Answer (score 0):

If you receive json and need converting date, try this:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp(1402680443);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Set to `setTimestamp()` method date value from your json object.